# POST requests not working in docker-compose container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, post, docker-compose

I have a problem with sending post requests to docker container build up with docker-compose method. When I send post request I receive 405 error -> "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL.". What is important is the fact that post requests work when I use the same container with docker run command. I guess that the problem might be docker-compose.yml file.

Dokckerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

EXPOSE 5005
WORKDIR /dialogflow_nlp_connector
COPY requirements.txt /dialogflow_nlp_connector
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ musl-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /dialogflow_nlp_connector/

CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

Docker-Compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    intent-handler:
        build: ./intent_handling
        volumes:
            - ./intent_handling:/dialogflow_nlp_connector
        environment:
            GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} 
            DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID: ${DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID}
        ports: 
            - "5005:5005"

    slack_event_handler:
        build: ./slack_events_api
        volumes:
            - ./slack_events_api:/slack_event_handler
        environment:
            SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${SLACK_BOT_TOKEN}
            SLACK_SIGNING_TOKEN: ${SLACK_SIGNING_TOKEN}
            SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN: ${SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN}
            FALLBACK_MESSAGE: "Sorry something went wrong :c Please try again in a moment!"
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Now even with docker run post requests are not working :c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment varibles should be a list

```
environment:
  - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} 
  - DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID=${DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID}
```

Also I don't see environment file in your docker-compose file. Refer this [URL](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Iif I add dashes like You did I got an error
```code
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.intent-handler.environment contains {"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": {"config/enviroment_variables/df-handling-test-4c3d81541aad.json": null}}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

Comment: How are you passing the variables? I had made a typo in my above reply, corrected it now. Correction --> variable_name=${value}

Comment: @Nitish docker compose will look for a .env file in the directory in which you run the command. It is not required to be explicitly specified in the docker-compose.yml file.